# 404 error handling for HTTPS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, http-status-code-404, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm very new to ASP.NET Core and trying to building my first website. I was struggling with the error handling and really need some advice.

To handle 404 error I was using code
        `app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");`  in startup.cs

With a Home Controller

```
    [HttpGet("Home/error/{errcode}")]
    public IActionResult Error(int errCode)
    {         
        return View("Error", errCode);            
    }
```

Which seems to successfully catch the 404,500 errors and displays the error views page with a correct code. The error view is in `/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml`

But when I add a redirect from HTTP to HTTPS like this in startup.cs

```
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.IsHttps)
            {
                await next();
            }
            else
            {
                var httpsUrl = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                context.Response.Redirect(httpsUrl);
            }
        });
```

The error handling won't work anymore and show `Secure Connection Failed` `Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG` in Firefox

Now it look like this.

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();
          if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error/{0}");
            // StatusCodePagesMiddleware to handle errors     
            app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/Home/Error/{0}");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=LandingPage}/{id?}");               
        });

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (context.Request.IsHttps)
            {
                await next();
            }
            else
            {
                var httpsUrl = "https://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.Path;
                context.Response.Redirect(httpsUrl);
            }
        });
     }
```

How can I handle error with HTTPS in ASP.NET MVC Core1.0 please?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: COuld you post your confiugration properties?

Comment: Do you mean this?
`{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:53519/",
      "sslPort": 0
    }
  },
  `

Comment: chnage the value of sslport and try again. In my working enviroment is set to 44300 and works perfectly

Comment: just tried to change to "sslPort": 44300 but still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Order if middlewares are important. You should first do redirect, then use MVC:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    // redirect
    ...
});

app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    ...
}
```